# Deserialize JSON json URL for query parameters in Specflow not working

Tags: c#, automated-tests, urlencode, specflow, visual-studio-test-runner

How to encode query parameters on a url in Specflow? the
GET Call for API with Search options  with changing scenarios as
Case with searchOperator used = equal, in, like

GET API  call for
`url.com/?SearchOptions=[{"Searchby":"title","searchOperator":"contains","searchValue1":"testing"}]`

stepdefination

```
 [When(@"Requesting for Search: (.*), (.*)")]
        public void WhenAGetRequestSearchOnly(string searchOption, int statusCode)
        {
            switch (statusCode)
            {
                case 401:
                    Token=invalidtoken";  - This pass
                case 200:
                    Token="invalidtoken"; -Failed 400 (def url is not encoded properly) 
                  break;
            }
            SetResponse(EndPoints.GetResponseSearchOnly(_Token, searchOption, statusCode));

        }
```

[image: specflow] - Same is coming in postman (which means url is not properly encoded)

Need url to hit - /endpointapi?SearchOptions=[{%22Searchby%22:%22title%22,%22searchOperator%22:%22contains%22,%22filterValue1%22:%22testing%22}]

API GET call works fine `url.com/?SearchOptions=[{"Searchby":"title","searchOperator":"contains","searchValue1":"testing",searchValue2":""}]`
When endoded this url it comes like this

`%7B%22SearchBy%22%3A%22title%22%2C%22SearchOperator%22%3A%22contains%22%2C%20%22SearchValue1%22%3A%22Testing%22%7D` which is giving above error

As an Example browser url is seen working fine (pls ignore the values of json)
[image: url captured as an example]

Note-
used [online json query encoder](https://jsonformatter.org/json-url-encode) filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved by using below reference

References:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0
- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-json-string-in-C-Sharp/

```
string json = "[{"Searchby":"title","searchOperator":"contains","searchValue1":"testing"}]";
var stringified = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json));
Console.WriteLine(stringified);
```

Prints:

```
"[{\"Searchby\":\"title\",\"searchOperator\":\"contains\",\"searchValue1\":\"testing\"}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below string:

```
%5B%7B%22Searchby%22%3A%22title%22%2C%22searchOperator%22%3A%22contains%22%2C%22searchValue1%22%3A%22testing%22%7D%5D
```

instead of:

```
[{"Searchby":"title","searchOperator":"contains","searchValue1":"testing"}]
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: I did Tried the string @JeremyCaney used

`%5B%7B%22Searchby%22%3A%22title%22%2C%22searchOperator%22%3A%22contains%22%2C%22searchValue1%22%3A%22testing%22%7D%5D` 

decoded to `%255B%257B%2522Searchby%2522%253A%2522title%2522%252C%2522searchOperator%2522%253A%2522contains%2522%252C%2522searchValue1%2522%253A%2522testing%2522%257D%255D` which is throwing 404